# Limit of $|\mathrm{Re}(a^n)|$ where $a=\frac12(1+i\sqrt7)$

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I must prove that with $a = \frac12(1+i\sqrt7)$ we have : $|\mathrm{Re}(a^n)| \to \infty$

I tried to use linear algebra by writing $u_n,v_n = Re(a^n), Im(a^n)$ and solve the homogeneous linear recurrence to find a new expression of $u_n$ but I am back to the starting point... The eigen values are as expected $a$ and $\bar{a}$

I also tried to compute $cos(n \times arg(a))$ but it is the same.

Any idea?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Can you compute the magnitude $a$?

Comment: Is there any chance that there would be a typo in the question? It is easy to prove $|a^n|\to\infty$. It seems hard to prove $|\text{Re}(a^n)|\to\infty$ and, if true at all (!), it may come up from the number-theoretic considerations (behaviour in the ring $\mathbb Z\left[\frac{1+i\sqrt{7}}{2}\right]$). Where's this problem coming from?

Comment: A friend asked me the riddle. It is in a subject of a math competition competition so the level can be hard.
It's been 2 days that we are ten trying to find the solution

Comment: see http://oeis.org/A002249  which led me to find the duplicate question...